# regex closest match digits

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of numbers
4
44
4420
44208
442082
4420820
44208202
4420820205
44208202057
442082020579

now I have the number 442082020987 , how can i get a regex search to find the closest match?

44?2?0?8?2?0?2?0?5?7?9? gives me all of them , is there a way to show the closest match?

thanks

Comment: I don't think you need regex in this. Subtract each number from the given number. Remove the `-` sign if there is any. The smallest difference will be closest match.

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? And does it have to be a regex solution? I would have thought regexes were particularly poorly suited to this

Comment: Depends if it's a numeric 'close' or a text 'close'. Being off by an order of magnitude might be 'closer' despite numerically not being. Either way - `regex` isn't the right tool.

Comment: Correct, these are phone numbers, these are all in string format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a case for `nmin_by` from the [`List::UtilsBy`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy) module

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::UtilsBy 'nmin_by';

chomp( my @data = <DATA> );

my $target = 442082020987;

say nmin_by { abs($_ - $target) } @data;

__DATA__
4
44
4420
44208
442082
4420820
44208202
4420820205
44208202057
442082020579
```

#### output

```
442082020579
```

If you would prefer to avoid using the module then this will do job. The output is identical to the first solution

```
for my $n ( @data ) {
    my $delta = abs($n - $target);
    unless ( defined $min_delta and $min_delta <= $delta ) {
        ($nearest, $min_delta) = ($n, $delta);
    }
}

say $nearest;
```

Comment: Cool. Numeric based, and text based comparison answers. That's pretty comprehensive ;)

Answer (score 3):

Regex is really the wrong tool for this job - regular expressions are about matching patterns. The task you're doing... isn't.

Try a different approach, like using [`Text::Levenshtein`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/lib/Text/Levenshtein.pm) to compare them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Levenshtein qw/ distance /;

my $search = '442082020987';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    print distance ( $search, $_ ), "=>", $_,"\n";
}

__DATA__
4
44
4420
44208
442082
4420820
44208202
4420820205
44208202057
442082020579
```

Output:

```
11=>4
10=>44
8=>4420
7=>44208
6=>442082
5=>4420820
4=>44208202
3=>4420820205
2=>44208202057
3=>442082020579
```

I'll leave it to you to select the minimum, assuming that: "`2 => 44208202057`" is the right answer for your scenario.

Or you could do a numeric comparison - but these look like phone numbers, so a string based match might be appropriate.

Comment: It never occurred to me that these may be telephone numbers—well spotted. `44` is the country code for the United Kingdom. This is why I asked what the OP meant by *“closest”*. I think we need a better description of the problem

Comment: I have it easy - I live in .uk so recognised it instantly. `0208` would be a London area code.

Comment: Me too—I'm up in Norfolk—but it didn't click with me because I expect to see it as `+44`